# VUE change value only after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a code like this. In this code, a user wants to change the current name. The current name is also displayed at top of the page.

```
// template
<div>{{ currentUser.name }}</div>
<v-text-field
   required
   v-model="currentUser.name"
   class="mb-3"
></v-text-field>
<v-btn>submit</v-btn>

//script
data() {
  currentUser: null
},
methods: {
  getUser(id) {
    //my GET method here
  },
  updateUser() {
    //my PUT method here
  }
```

The data is from an API. The current `v-text-field` is filled with the current name. Right now, if I change the value in the text field, the `div` value also changes. How to make it change only when the user has already clicked (let's say) a submit button and the process succeed?

Answer (score 1):

This may work fine

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ currentUser.name }}</div>
    <v-text-field required class="mb-3" ref="textField"></v-text-field>
    <button @click="updateUsername">update user's name</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentUser: {
        name: '',
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateUsername() {
      this.currentUser.name = this.$refs.textField.internalValue
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

You could also use a `debounce`, store it in another state but having to use a `$refs` is okay here.

Also, I'm not a Vuetify user, hence I'm not sure what all of those `value` are about but you have some nice choice overall.

[image]

Comment: It says `internalValue does not exist on type Vue element`. Also can I put `this.currentUser.name = this.$refs.textField.internalValue` line inside the updateName methods (with PUT method). Sorry I'm still kinda processing your answer

Comment: @tara yeah, you could send that value to your API, no issues so far. As for the error, not sure why it does work on my side and not yours. Did you add the `ref` on it? Also, feel free to console.log + Vue devtools to see what is happening with your components.

Comment: yes, I did put the `ref` part. It's just I didn't add the `currentUser: {
        name: '',
      },` part because I already have that but I write it like this `currentUser: null` because I'm going to store the user data from my API to that variable

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Kissu's answer, if you wish to change the value on `blur` (when you click away), you have to do the following.

Since Vuetify does not provide a `lazy` prop to only allow value update on `change` event, you have to do it yourself. Use the `:value` prop and bind it to a computed property and provide a getter setter to the computed property.

This will only trigger the change on `blur`, when you click away from the input, or press enter or press tab.

```
<template>
  <div>{{ currentUserName }}</div>
  <v-text-field
     required
     :value="currentUserName"
     @change="onNameChange"
     class="mb-3"
  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
...

methods: {
  onNameChange(event) {
    this.currentUserName = event.target.value;
  }
}
computed: {
  currentUserName: {
    get() {
       return this.currentUser.name
    }, 
    set(newName) {
       this.currentUser.name = newName;   
    }
  }
}

...
</script>
```

Comment: This is on `blur` and not on button click tho.

Comment: My bad, I hastily read the question. @kissu answer is correct if you only wish for a simple update on a button click.

Comment: No issues per-se. It's a nice alternative too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div>{{ currentUser.name }}</div>
<v-text-field
   required
   :value="currentUser.name"
   @input="nameChanged" //here maybe @change="xxx"
   class="mb-3"
></v-text-field>
<v-btn @click="updateUser">submit</v-btn>

//script
data() {
  currentUser: null
},
methods: {
  nameChanged(e) {
    console.log(`e`,e) //The value is based on the printed value

    this.tempName = e
  },
  updateUser() {
    this.currentUser.name = this.tempName
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71899584/vue-change-value-only-after-clicking-submit/71909624#comment127058361_71901369

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).